# animateScrollToItem in flutter

Tags: flutter-animation, flutter-listview

Is there a function like `animateScrollToItem` in flutter like in jetpack compose?
I have a `ListView` with horizontal scroll. The item further left or right might be a bit off screen. My focus is that when the user click on them the item is scrolled to so that it becomes fully visible.

I am aware of the `ScrollController.animateTo` but it doesn't seem to be straightforward .